# HFS+ on fedora, many broken directory hard link

Tags: linux, fedora, hard-link, hfs+

There is a hard disk. In one directory there are around 1000 directories, and every each one hard linked to other location in the same hard. the problem is that in fedora 35 of them I could open, the other seems broken and doen't refer to anything (with a different icon).

Currently hfsplusutils installed on my machine, I also tried different hfs+ package but there were no luck.

**UPDATE 1:**
To clarify my question, my problem is I have many movies each in one directory. I organized them with the help of directory hard-link facility of HFS+ and they are quite like the scheme below where each movie hard linked to appropriate location in Category based on  their Rate, Genre, ....

```
Archive/
       All/
           Movie_1/
           Movie_2/
           Movie_3/
           ...
           ...
       Category/
                Genre/
                       Comedy/
                              Movie_1/
                              Movie_2/
                              ...
                       Action/
                              Movie_3/
                              ...
                       ...
                Rate/ 
                     9/
                       Movie_2/
                     8/
                     ...
                Director/
                        ...
```

**I can't access to many of my movies which hard-linked.** Other files and directories which are not hard-linked they all fine. My distrubution is Fedora.

What is the cause, how to solve it?

Comment: Are you looking at an Apple Time Machine archive?

Comment: @Kusalananda, Acually not, it's result of a software I wrote, and it was fine on my Mac book, and it's a while I don't have access to my laptop.

Comment: @roaima I added extra explanation to clarify my question.

Comment: What _directories_ are hard linked, and what _files_ are hard linked in that listing? I'm just trying to clarify whether you're actually hard-linking any directories at all. Unfortunately I don't know whether Linux's HFS+ supports hard linked directories or not.

Comment: @Kusalananda all the directories in the "All" directory hard-linked. They are about 1000 and about 35 of them are accessible. (and no files hard-linked just directories)

Comment: Although either the querstion probably wasn't interesting enough or it was very obscure, I found a tools which helped me to access my data, the tool name is [hfsexplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer).

Comment: If you can write an answer, that would be good (just noticed that the question was closed, so that won't be possible unfortunately). Yes, it's very uncommon to deal with hard-linked directories, so the whole issue is a bit obscure.